# plotting data on chart using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

The following 2 div's is used to hold the users 'name' and 'birthday'.
Once the user enters their 'name' and 'birthday', it then appears on the HTML page.
Currently there is 6 users 'name' and 'birthday' on the page.

```
    <div id="name"> </div>
    <div id="birthday"></div>
```

How can I make this data appear in a chart format? So that the 6 user 'names' and 'birthdays' will appear on the chart?

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      animationEnabled: true,
      legend: {
        cursor:"pointer",
        itemclick : function(e) {
          if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
              e.dataSeries.visible = false;
          }
          else {
              e.dataSeries.visible = true;
          }
          chart.render();
        }
      },
      axisY: {
        title: "Time"
      },
      toolTip: {
        shared: true,  
        content: function(e){
          var str = '';
          var total = 0 ;
          var str3;
          var str2 ;
          for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++){
            var  str1 = "<span style= 'color:"+e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "'> " + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: <strong>"+  e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + "</strong> <br/>" ; 
            total = e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + total;
            str = str.concat(str1);
          }
          str2 = "<span style = 'color:DodgerBlue; '><strong>"+e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong></span><br/>";
          str3 = "<span style = 'color:Tomato '>Total: </span><strong>" + total + "</strong><br/>";

          return (str2.concat(str)).concat(str3);
        }

      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Names and Birthdays",
        color: "#000000",
        dataPoints: [
            { y: May, label: "Peter"},
            { y: April, label: "Anne"},
            { y: March, label: "Paul"},        
            { y: June, label: "Sarah"},         


        ]
      },
      ]
    });

chart.render();
}
</script>
```

So instead on this hard coded values?

```
 data: [
          {        
            type: "bar",
            showInLegend: true,
            name: "Names and Birthdays",
            color: "#000000",
            dataPoints: [
            { y: May, label: "Peter"},
            { y: April, label: "Anne"},
            { y: March, label: "Paul"},        
            { y: June, label: "Sarah"},        


            ]
          },
          ]
        });
```

How can I take in this data instead?

```
    <div id="name"> </div>
    <div id="birthday"></div>
```

Comment: It is not clear how you want this to actually be plotted. Or how you will handle multiple people in one month. I am confused why you would want this in a chart, rather than just a table or list, or maybe a calendar?  Or how the information for multiple people is stored - you've only shown a single element with unique ids, that can't be repeated multiple times.

Comment: I was just playing around with some JavaScript and trying to plot data into a chart to see how it would work. How is it not possible to take these values into a chart?

Comment: Well, again, you have to define what you mean by "take them into a chart". What do you want the chart to actually do?  Provide an illustration, and more info on exactly how the data is stored on the page.

Comment: data is already being stored and is displayed using the 2 divs. the chart is already being displayed. i just need the data to display the name and birthday.

Comment: take them into chart: display data in chart :)

Comment: That doesn't say anything about how you want to plot the data in the chart. And it still doesn't answer how the data is stored on the page - you have two divs shown in your code. But you have 4 names in your data - so you need 8 divs, and they can't all have ids of "name" and "birthday" - ids must be unique.  Provide an illustration of what you want a chart to do with your information - because what you have so far does not make sense as something to put on a chart.

Comment: @usermb1989 You could load data from HTML table using data module - more info in the [Docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9eeamsww/